# change HTML background color

Tags: colors, background-color

how can i change the red color in this page to #7c6baf color
how can i change the red color in this page to #7c6baf color
how can i change the red color in this page to #7c6baf color
how can i change the red color in this page to #7c6baf color
how can i change the red color in this page to #7c6baf color
how can i change the red color in this page to #7c6baf color
how can i change the red color in this page to #7c6baf color
how can i change the red color in this page to #7c6baf color

https://media1screen.blogspot.com/